# How to format an HTTP POST Request for Facebook Pages Graph API for hours

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am a beginner when it comes to HTTP API requests. Especially with Facebook. How do I format an update to my page's hours? The end goal is to update them dynamically.

When I try 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/tbxisu?method=post&access_token=[token]&hours=mon_1_open=10:00

in the API Explorer, or in my browser it returns: "param hours must be an object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to structure your call similar to the below

`hours={"mon_1_open":"10:00","mon_1_close":"19:00"}`

so your above call would be

POST
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/tbxisu?method=post&access_token=[token]&hours={"mon_1_open":"10:00","mon_1_close":"19:00"}`

You can do other days too in same call, eg updating Monday and Tuesday would be 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/tbxisu?access_token=[token]&hours={"mon_1_open":"03:00","mon_1_close":"21:00","tue_1_open":"21:00","tue_1_close":"23:00"}` etc